# Color coding a text string with alternating colors

Tags: color, luatex

I was wondering if it was possible to color every second letter in a text string in `LaTeX`. I'm writing a report on decrypting a Vigenere cipher, and have a text string that I would like to have every alternate letter be colored differently.

So for example the string might be 'abcdefg', and I would like the output to show 'aceg' in blue and 'bdf' in red, or something like that.
Is this easily feasible in `LaTeX`?

Thank you guys!

Comment: Did you mean automatically?  The simple-but-tedious way with `color` package is just to do `\textcolor{red}{a}\textcolor{blue}{b}` etc

Comment: Did you mean to use the `luatex` tag?  Are you looking for a lua solution?

Comment: And while I'm at it... Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @Thruston Yes -- I advised OP to post this question here. [It was originally posted on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/LaTeX/comments/3yvxy2/color_coding_a_text_string/cyhpl2g) where there are *far* fewer LuaTeX users.

Comment: In ciphertext spaces are usually ignored. Is this your case?

Comment: @Thruston Yeah, Sean referred me to post my question here. My original document is in just normal LaTeX (I'm a beginner to all this; writing one of my first reports), but I'm open to any solution.

Comment: @egreg That's alright, I just have a chunk of letters where I'm pulling out every other letter or every third letter, and I want to make it more clear through the use of colors

Answer (score 8):

Here's an `expl3` version for alternating colours, but not for strings with whitespace (so far)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand{\colorstring}[3]{% 
  \str_set:Nn \l_tmpa_str {#3}% store the string to a string variable
  % Now loop through the string variable and get each 'letter' 
  \int_step_inline:nnnn {1} {1} {\str_count:N \l_tmpa_str } {%
    \int_if_odd:nTF{##1}{% Is the number odd → use the first colour
      \textcolor{#1}{\str_item:Nn \l_tmpa_str {##1}}
    }{% No, use the 2nd colour
      \textcolor{#2}{\str_item:Nn \l_tmpa_str {##1}}
    }%
  }%
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\bfseries
\huge \colorstring{blue}{red}{abcdefgh}


\huge \colorstring{brown}{Green4}{ABCEDEFGH}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Another version, with alternating colours**

... and providing more than two colours, as well as using in an environment. However, no empty lines are allowed! No real tests on printable characters are done so far.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{environ}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\colorstring}{O{blue,red}+m}{%
  \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {#1}%
  \int_zero:N \l_tmpa_int%
  \str_set:Nx \l_tmpa_str {#2}%
  \int_step_inline:nnnn {1} {1} {\str_count:N \l_tmpa_str } {%
    \str_case_x:nnF {\str_item:Nn \l_tmpa_str {##1}} {%
      {\space}{\space}
    }{%
      \int_compare:nNnTF {\l_tmpa_int } < {\clist_count:N \l_tmpa_clist } {
        \int_incr:N \l_tmpa_int
      }{%
        \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int {\c_one}
      }
      \textcolor{\clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {\l_tmpa_int }}{\str_item:Nn \l_tmpa_str {##1}}
    }
  }
}



\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewEnviron{ColorLettersInternal}[1]{\colorstring[#1]{\BODY}} % Internal environment for `\Body`

\NewDocumentEnvironment{ColorLetters}{O{blue,red}}{%
  \ttfamily%
  \ColorLettersInternal{#1}%
}{%
  \endColorLettersInternal%
}


\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}


\bfseries
\huge \colorstring{abcdefgh}
\huge \colorstring[brown,Green4,Aquamarine4]{ABCEDEFGH}

\colorstringnew[violet,Green4,Red4,Blue2]{TCGATGGAGGGACCAT}

\begin{ColorLetters}[Blue4,Red4,Green4,LightBlue4]
And now for something completely different
Number Three -- the Larch!
\end{ColorLetters}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could this be adaptable to use as an environment?

Comment: And couldn't you use `\exp_args:` to say `\textcolor{\int_if_odd: ...}`?

Comment: @SeanAllred: I am still new to `expl3` .... thanks for any suggestion. About the environment: Well, I must grab the environment body then,  I assume?

Comment: This works with `color` I guess, as well as `xcolor`.

Comment: @Thruston: Of course, but the colornames may be different (I am not sure `color provides the `x11names` etc. color names sets)

Comment: For this solution, yes -- I imagine you'd have to grab the entire body, fully expand it (to get any macro-replacements out of the way), and then go through the token list one by one to see if the token is in fact a printing character. Not my idea of a fun time :-)

Comment: @SeanAllred: I've a solution already for this `environment`. I'll still struggle with 'whitespace'

Comment: @SeanAllred: See the update please

Comment: @ChristianHupfer So this's probably a really stupid question, but what does 'an expl3 version' entail? My current report's on Overleaf (working on multiple computers and easier file sharing and stuff for highschool), and if I try to copy and paste, overleaf returns errors. Should I move off Overleaf for this?

Overleaf has a problem with 
`\huge \colorstring{blue}{red}{abcdefgh}`

and returns an undefined control sequence error. Thank you for your help by the way!

Comment: @Kaddon: `expl3` is the 'new' LaTeX version with a different syntax (as you can see from the code). I don't know anything about OverLeaf -- apparently it doesn't support the `expl3` or `xparse` package or has outdated packages.

Comment: @Kaddon expl3 is a programming environment built on top of plain ole' TeX -- it doesn't require LuaTeX. As you might've noticed, however, it *does* require a relatively up-to-date distribution. Online compilers are notorious for not being very accommodating, here.

Answer (score 5):

Here, I use a simple recursion, until the end of the string is reached.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\colorstring[3]{\def\colorA{#1}\def\colorB{#2}\colorstringhelp#3%
  \relax\relax\relax}
\def\colorstringhelp#1#2#3\relax{\textcolor{\colorA}{#1}\textcolor{\colorB}{#2}%
  \ifx\relax#3\else\colorstringhelp#3\relax\relax\fi}
\begin{document}%
\colorstring{blue}{red}{abcdef}\par
\colorstring{green}{orange}{abcdefg}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since ciphertext is usually typeset without spaces, doing a mapping on the input is simple (and automatically gobbles spaces). With `environ` we can define an environment that collects its body.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{environ}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \l_kaddon_colors_seq
\int_new:N \l_kaddon_color_int

\cs_new_protected:Nn \kaddon_color_string:nn
 {
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_kaddon_colors_seq { #1 }
  \int_zero:N \l_kaddon_color_int
  \tl_map_inline:nn { #2 } { \kaddon_color:n { ##1 } }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \kaddon_color_string:nn { nV }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \kaddon_color:n
 {
  \int_incr:N \l_kaddon_color_int
  \int_compare:nT { \l_kaddon_color_int > \seq_count:N \l_kaddon_colors_seq }
   { % exhausted colors, restart
    \int_set:Nn \l_kaddon_color_int { 1 }
   }
  \str_if_eq:nnTF { #1 } { \par }
   {
    \int_decr:N \l_kaddon_color_int
    \par
   }
   {
    \textcolor{\seq_item:Nn \l_kaddon_colors_seq { \l_kaddon_color_int } } { #1 }
    \hspace{0pt plus 0.1pt }
   }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\colorstring}{ O{red,blue} m }
 {
  \kaddon_color_string:nn { #1 } { #2 }
  \unskip % remove the last \hspace
 }

\NewEnviron{colorpar}[1][red,blue]
 {
  \begin{quote}
  \kaddon_color_string:nV { #1 } \BODY
  \end{quote}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\colorstring{abcdefgh}

\colorstring[red,red,blue]{abcd efgh}

\colorstring[brown,Green4,Aquamarine4]{ABCEDEFGH abcdef}

\begin{colorpar}[Blue4,Red4,Green4,LightBlue4]
And now for something completely different
And now for something completely different
And now for something completely different
And now for something completely different
\end{colorpar}

\begin{colorpar}
And now for something completely different
And now for something completely different

And now for something completely different
And now for something completely different
\end{colorpar}

\end{document}
```

[image]