# Alternating colors in a string of text per word

Tags: color, text

I'm looking for something like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285968/color-coding-a-text-string-with-alternating-colors), where a string of text can be put into a command that alternates the text between colors (preferably three), but the color is per word.

eg, \alternatecolors{blah blah blah} would result in three blahs, the first in red, second green, third blue; if there are more then it repeats from red→green→blue etc.

I am currently using the simple solution of just coloring each word independently but I have a lot of instances of this and am in the process of rewriting the entire document :), so I'm interested if this is actually feasible before I rewrite more.

Thank you!

Comment: What about punctuation? Should it share the color of the word it's attached to?

Answer (score 4):

Welcome! You only need `xcolor`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\makeatletter
\def\alternatecolors#1{\colorlet{oldcolor}{.}\my@color%
    \@alternatecolors#1 \@empty
    \color{oldcolor}
}
\def\@alternatecolors#1 #2{%
   #1\my@color\space
   \ifx #2\@empty\else
    \expandafter\@alternatecolors
   \fi
   #2%
}
\newcounter{pft@col}
\newcommand{\my@color}{\ifcase\value{pft@col}%
 \color{red}%
 \stepcounter{pft@col}%
\or
 \color{green}%
 \stepcounter{pft@col}%
\or
 \color{blue}%
 \setcounter{pft@col}{0}%
\fi}
\newcommand{\ResetColor}{\setcounter{pft@col}{0}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\alternatecolors{blah blah blah} : % 
\alternatecolors{blah blub pft pfft} : %
\alternatecolors{blah blub pft pfft} : %
\alternatecolors{blah blub pft pfft} : %
\alternatecolors{blah blub pft pfft} : \ResetColor%
\alternatecolors{blah blub pft pfft} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

The color cycle gets continued unless one resets it with `\ResetColor`. Of course, one may also reset it by default if that's needed.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**: With `soul` and `xcolor` you could do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\alternatecolors}{%
  \SOUL@setup
  \def\SOUL@preamble{\colorlet{oldcolor}{.}\my@color}%
  \def\SOUL@postamble{\color{oldcolor}}%
  \def\SOUL@everyspace##1{##1\my@color\space}%
  \def\SOUL@everytoken{\the\SOUL@token}%
  \SOUL@
}
\newcounter{pft@col}
\newcommand{\my@color}{\ifcase\value{pft@col}%
 \color{red}%
 \stepcounter{pft@col}%
\or
 \color{green}%
 \stepcounter{pft@col}%
\or
 \color{blue}%
 \setcounter{pft@col}{0}%
\fi}
\newcommand{\ResetColor}{\setcounter{pft@col}{0}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\alternatecolors{blah blah blah} : % 
\alternatecolors{blah blub pft pfft} : %
\alternatecolors{blah blub pft pfft} : %
\alternatecolors{blah blub pft pfft} : %
\alternatecolors{blah blub pft pfft} : \ResetColor%
\alternatecolors{blah blub pft pfft} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you!

Is there any way to make this command act like a `{\itshape blah}` kind of command?  I'm using expex and it only takes those kind of commands for some things I think?

Also how would one make it automatically reset after the command? I'm kinda new to this kind of depth to commands >.<

Comment: @Maxine Most likely there is. Yet you have never bothered to accept this answer, which, as I believe, answers the original question. I'd kindly like to ask you to accept this answer if you think it solves your original problem, and ask a new question for your new problem.